# Count rows until criterion is reached, then start again

Tags: r, counter, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
time=c(20,30,1100,40,31,32,33,1005,22,23,1001,24,12,13,14,1002)
test <- data.frame(id,time)
```

I am now trying to count the rows until `time > 1000`grouped by `id` . So far I got

```
library(dplyr) 
test %>%    
group_by(id, idx = cumsum(time >= 1000))
%>%    
mutate(trip_count = row_number()) %>%    
ungroup %>%   
select(-idx)
```

This works so far but instead of `1` when `time > 1000` I want the count to go one further and starting with `1`again at the next column. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each group has 4 rows in your data, we can use this:

```
> test %>% left_join(test %>% filter(time < 1000) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(trip_count = row_number())) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
+                                                       mutate(trip_count = replace_na(trip_count, 4))
Joining, by = c("id", "time")
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
      id  time trip_count
   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1    20          1
 2     1    30          2
 3     1    40          3
 4     1  1100          4
 5     2    31          1
 6     2    32          2
 7     2    33          3
 8     2  1005          4
 9     3    22          1
10     3    23          2
11     3    24          3
12     3  1001          4
13     4    12          1
14     4    13          2
15     4    14          3
16     4  1002          4
>
```

If your data doesn't have 4 rows per group, can use this:

```
> id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
> time=c(20,30,40,1100,31,32,33,1005,22,23,24,1001,12,13,14,15,1002)
> test <- data.frame(id,time)
> test %>% left_join(test %>% filter(time < 1000) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(trip_count = row_number())) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
+               mutate(across(trip_count, ~ replace(., is.na(.), n())))
Joining, by = c("id", "time")
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
      id  time trip_count
   <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
 1     1    20          1
 2     1    30          2
 3     1    40          3
 4     1  1100          4
 5     2    31          1
 6     2    32          2
 7     2    33          3
 8     2  1005          4
 9     3    22          1
10     3    23          2
11     3    24          3
12     3  1001          4
13     4    12          1
14     4    13          2
15     4    14          3
16     4    15          4
17     4  1002          5
>
```

I added additional row to group 4.

Based on new data as shared by OP:

```
> test %>% 
+   left_join(test %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(row_number() < which(time >= 1000)) %>% 
+   mutate(trip_count = row_number())) %>% 
+   left_join(test %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(row_number() > which(time >= 1000)) %>% mutate(trip_count1 = row_number())) %>% 
+                     mutate(trip_count = coalesce(trip_count, trip_count1)) %>% select(-trip_count1) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
+                       mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% rowwise() %>%  mutate(trip_count = replace_na(trip_count, rowid)) %>% select(-rowid)
Joining, by = c("id", "time")
Joining, by = c("id", "time")
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Rowwise:  id
      id  time trip_count
   <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
 1     1    20          1
 2     1    30          2
 3     1  1100          3
 4     1    40          1
 5     2    31          1
 6     2    32          2
 7     2    33          3
 8     2  1005          4
 9     3    22          1
10     3    23          2
11     3  1001          3
12     3    24          1
13     4    12          1
14     4    13          2
15     4    14          3
16     4  1002          4
>
```

Comment: Hey, @KarthikS, thanks so much for your suggestion. I tried it with my data but it seems like there is a problem with your `across`function. Somehow he can't find this function that is why I get an error `can't find function "across" `

Comment: Which version of dplyr is being used? I think it works with 1.0.0 version dplyr. If prior dplyr version is used, better to upgrade.

Comment: I am using the version 0.8.0.1

Comment: So it seems to work now, however, the count is not stored in the data frame as a new coloumn. If it try to do so by saving `test$trip_count <- ...`it get the error: `Error: Assigned data "value" must be compatible with existing data.`Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: you need to store the output back into original dataframe or another dataframe if you wish to: test <- test %>% left_join(test %>% filter(time < 1000) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(trip_count = row_number())) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
               mutate(across(trip_count, ~ replace(., is.na(.), n())))

Comment: I see. So I did as you say but now the new dataframe test is more than four times the size of my initial data frame (18gb instead of 4gb) which means I can't work with it since I only have 16gb RAM. Also somehow the number of observations raised from 50000 to 2190000 and columns raised from 11 to 23. I don't know what is going on here :D Can you think of a different approach to count the rows?

Comment: OK, you need not select the duplicate columns, you can include the columns you need using select operation like this: test %>% left_join(test %>% filter(time < 1000) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(trip_count = row_number()) %>% select(COLUMNS HERE)) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(across(trip_count, ~ replace(., is.na(.), n())))

Comment: Okay, thanks, that looks better. But there are a couple of problems here now. First, your code sets `time` in my dataset to 0 except for the rows which meet the criterion `>1000`. In this rows, it sets to count to 5601 for some reason and then it keeps counting after that even though I want it to start with 1 again. Could you think of some reasons for that? Espacially the set time = 0 part?

Comment: So I fixed the part with set time = 0 but still it keeps counting even after those rows and it does not start with 1 again

Comment: My code doesn't operate on time column, it just uses in filtering but doesn't modify it anyway. Not sure why you are getting time = 0?

Comment: Two things on that: First, I don't see where you tell the count to start again after time > 1000. In my example it just starts from 1 again because the id changes but what if there are some more time values for the same id after that which I want to count new starting from 1? Secondly I don't unterstand wit what you replace the NAs in the join. Because it seems like right now they get replaced by the total number of rows, it this possible?

Comment: I am filter the rows below 1000 using filter(time < 1000), then I am starting the count using rownumbers. So if you take id 4 in the data I provided above, time 12 starts at 1 and time 15 ends at 4, now I am joining this to the original table test, so now, the row that has value > 1000, i.e. time 1002 in id 4 will have NA, I am replace that with row number for that id group, as there 5 numbers in that id, the NA value is replace by 5.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the clarification. The point I am trying to make is that I want the count to start again from one after each row >1000 even if it's the same id. Grouping by id only servers as preventing the count to go on over ids :-)

Comment: so what do you want the >1000 row value in trip_count to be?

Comment: 4, like it is in the example. But right now the count starts with 1 again after >1000 because the id changes. i want it to start with 1 again because the last value was >1000. Do you understand what I mean? E.g. move the >1000 values one to the left when creating the data frame. Maybe my problem becomes clear :-)

Comment: So the >1000 value should have same value as previous non- > 1000 value?

Comment: I edited the code for creating the test set in my question. When you run your solution on the new test set it becomes clear that the trip count changes because of a change in id rather than because of a row with time >1000. Let me know if this helps to understand my problem.

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for accepting my answer, have made the changes as you described, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%    
  group_by(id, idx = cumsum(lag(time, default = 0) >= 1000)) %>%    
  mutate(trip_count = row_number()) %>%    
  ungroup %>%   
  select(-idx)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id  time trip_count
   <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
 1     1    20          1
 2     1    30          2
 3     1    40          3
 4     1  1100          4
 5     2    31          1
 6     2    32          2
 7     2    33          3
 8     2  1005          4
 9     3    22          1
10     3    23          2
11     3    24          3
12     3  1001          4
13     4    12          1
14     4    13          2
15     4    14          3
16     4  1002          4
```

Comment: Hey, @arg0naut91 thanks for your suggestion. It works perfectly with this small test data set, however, it causes me multiple problems with my real, way larger data set. I think, I have to try a different approach.

Comment: What are multiple problems?